# Xamarin - Android - Verify server's SSL Cert manually ModernHttpClient

Tags: ssl, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get the SSL cert for the server and verify it manually.  I can't seem to get it working using either NativeMessageHandler (ModernHttpClient).

Here is the the request code:

```
var handler = (HttpClientHandler)Locator.CurrentMutable.GetService(typeof(HttpClientHandler));
var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(Config.ApiBaseUrl.ToString(), handler);
disco = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();
```

With ModernHttpClient/NativeMessageHandler if I try to use

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
        {
            var certAvailable = certificate != null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"cert exists: {certAvailable}");
            if (certAvailable)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Issuer: {certificate.Issuer}");
            }

            return true;
        };
```

but when sending the request, the cert is null. Why is the cert null?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a guess here, but in my experience Xamarin.Android can't handle async calls:

disco = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();